# datasource configuration "default" was not found in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP e PHPUnit to execute tests but when I execute a TestCase this error is prompted for every test method:

> 1) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest::testInitialize
>   Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException: The datasource configuration "default" was not found.

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        //'port' => 'nonstandard_port_number',
        'username' => 'dbusername',
        'password' => 'dbpass',
        'database' => 'dbname',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,

        /**
         * Set identifier quoting to true if you are using reserved words or
         * special characters in your table or column names. Enabling this
         * setting will result in queries built using the Query Builder having
         * identifiers quoted when creating SQL. It should be noted that this
         * decreases performance because each query needs to be traversed and
         * manipulated before being executed.
         */
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

        /**
         * During development, if using MySQL < 5.6, uncommenting the
         * following line could boost the speed at which schema metadata is
         * fetched from the database. It can also be set directly with the
         * mysql configuration directive 'innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'
         * which is the recommended value in production environments
         */
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
    ],
    /**
     * The test connection is used during the test suite.
     */
    'test' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        //'port' => 'nonstandard_port_number',
        'username' => 'dbusername',
        'password' => 'dbpass',
        'database' => 'dbnametest',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
    ],
],
```

The TestSuite:

```
<?php
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Table\UsersTable;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;

/**
 * App\Model\Table\UsersTable Test Case
 */
class UsersTableTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * Fixtures
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $fixtures = [
        'app.users',
        'app.user_types',
        'app.bookings',
        'app.stores'
    ];

    /**
     * setUp method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $config = TableRegistry::exists('Users') ? [] : ['className' => 'App\Model\Table\UsersTable'];
        $this->Users = TableRegistry::get('Users', $config);
    }

    /**
     * tearDown method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function tearDown()
    {
        unset($this->Users);

        parent::tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * Test initialize method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testInitialize()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.');
    }

    /**
     * Test validationDefault method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    // Método que deverá testar o método "validationDefault()" de "UsersTable",
    // mas como e quando este método será chamado?
    // A ferramenta seleciona o método a ser executado
    public function testValidationDefault()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.');
    }

    /**
     * Test buildRules method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBuildRules()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.');
    }

    public function testFindUserById(){
        $query = $this->Users->find('userById', [
            'conditions' => ['Users.id' => 900000],
            'fields' => ['Users.id', 'Users.email', 'Users.password',
                'Users.username', 'Users.user_type_id', 'Users.created',
                'Users.modified']
        ]);
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Cake\ORM\Query', $query);
        $result = $query->hydrate(false)->toArray();

        $expected = [
            [
                'id' => 900000,
                'email' => 'usuariocomum1@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'usuariocomum1senha',
                'username' => 'usuariocomum1username',
                'user_type_id' => 900000,
                'created' => '2015-07-17 18:46:47',
                'modified' => '2015-07-17 18:46:47'
            ]
        ];

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
    }
}
```

But the datasource "default" and "test" it's OK, the site works fine.

Full command line:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\bin>phpunit "C:/xampp/htdocs/PROJETOS/S
hopping/tests/TestCase/Model/Table/UsersTableTest.php"
PHPUnit 4.8.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

EEEE

Time: 3.85 seconds, Memory: 3.75Mb

There were 4 errors:

1) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest::testInitialize
Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException: The datasource confi
guration "default" was not found.

C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\Connecti
onManager.php:188
C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\TableRegistry.p
hp:192
C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\tests\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest.php:
35

2) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest::testValidationDefault
Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException: The datasource confi
guration "default" was not found.

C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\Connecti
onManager.php:188
C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\TableRegistry.p
hp:192
C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\tests\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest.php:
35

3) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest::testBuildRules
Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException: The datasource confi
guration "default" was not found.

C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\Connecti
onManager.php:188
C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\TableRegistry.p
hp:192
C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\tests\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest.php:
35

4) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest::testFindUserById
Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException: The datasource confi
guration "default" was not found.

C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\Connecti
onManager.php:188
C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\TableRegistry.p
hp:192
C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\tests\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest.php:
35

FAILURES!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 0, Errors: 4.
```

I test now (01/09/2015 (1st september) - 09:56) and doesn't error in [projectName]/logs/cli-error and [projectName]/logs/error with this date.

**NOTE:** CakePHP version 3.0.11

Comment: Besides that tests should use the `test` connection (where `default` will be an alias for `test`), check your CLI error log (`logs/cli-error.log`), errors always have a stacktrace that should be included in the question. Also please mention your exact CakePHP version (`vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`).

Comment: @ndm I add the information in my question

Comment: Don't rely solely on the dates in the error logs, empty them, run the test-suite, then check them again. Also make sure that the files are writable.

Comment: @ndm I add my TestFile, I run the tests again but nothing was wrote in both files (I check and are writable).

Comment: Sounds fishy... what does the command for running the tests look like?

Comment: @ndm I add my full comand line

Comment: There you have it, you're not invoking PHPUnit correctly.

Comment: @ndm how I could invoke it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running the test suite correctly, what you are doing there will cause PHPUnit to not pick up the test suite configuration that lives in your applications root (`phpunit.xml.dist`)

As per the docs, you should run the suite from your applications root directory

> [...]
>
> By using `phpunit` you can run your application tests. To run your application’s tests you can simply run:
>
> ```
> // composer installs
> $ vendor/bin/phpunit
>
> // phar file
> php phpunit.phar
> ```
>
> **From your application’s root directory.**
>
> [...]

<sup>* *emphasis mine*</sup>

**[Cookbook > Testing > Running Tests](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#running-tests)**

So you should CD into the `Shopping` directoy, and run PHPUnit using a relative path like

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping
vendor\bin\phpunit tests\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest.php
```

Comment: Windows users ensure you are running from the windows powershell

Comment: @i_am_leo That's by no means required.

Answer (score 0):

First set up a test database and then add this to your app.php file:

```
 'test' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'YOUR TEST HOST',
            'username' => 'USERNAME',
            'password' => 'PASSWORD',
            'database' => 'YOUR TEST DB',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
            //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        ],
```