# CakePHP 3 fixtures not Importing

Tags: php, phpunit, cakephp-3.0, fixtures

I am using phpunit for testing a CakePHP 3 Controller. The problem is that it does not importing the fixtures. It is just importing live DB data. Reading and writing just uses the LIVE DB even though I have defined a test DB and fixtures. Am I doing something wrong below?

My Fixture

```
class ToursFixture extends TestFixture {

    public $connection = 'test';
    public $fields = [
    'id' => ['type' => 'integer'],
    'title' => ['type' => 'string', 'length' => 255, 'null' => false],
    'created' => 'datetime',
    'modified' => 'datetime'
    '_constraints' => [
        'primary' => ['type' => 'primary', 'columns' => ['id']]
    ]
];

public $records = [
    [
        'title' => 'tour 1',
        'created' => '2015-07-24 09:15:48',
        'modified' => '2015-07-24 09:15:48',
    ],
];
```

}

My Test Class

```
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;
use App\Controller\ToursController;
use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

require '../../bootstrap.php';

class ToursControllerTest extends IntegrationTestCase {

    public $fixtures = ['app.tours'];
```

App Config DB

```
'test' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
```

Comment: `require '../../bootstrap.php';` ??? The bootstrap file is by default defined in the PHPUnit configuration, and loaded automatically!

Comment: When I leave it out I get a "Fatal error: Class 'Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase' not found" error

Comment: Then you're probably not invoking PHPUnit correctly, and/or composer isn't setup properly. What does the command look like?

Comment: phpunit ToursControllerTest.php

Comment: That's definitely not the correct way. **http://stackoverflow.com/a/32332890/1392379**